# Cross project Job usage in rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am having multiple project in rundeck (Version : Rundeck 2.11.4-1)

Project A -> JOB A

Project B -> JOB B

Project C -> JOB C which will call JOB A and Job B.
Project A,B,C having different resource xml .Hence having different value against same properties in resource xml.
So when I am running the JOB C from Project C . Its look up the resource xml of Project C.
What I am looking for is how can I ensure JOB A use Project A resource xml and JOB B use Project B
resource xml even if its actually call from Project C.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your scenario, and the solution is to update to the latest Rundeck version (3.4.7 at this moment) to use the "Use references job's nodes." [capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIRE9.jpg) in the job reference step, this option isn't available on 2.11.x.

In that way, you can [achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX8Kw.jpg) your goal.

Alternatively (and as a "dirty" solution) is to call the JobA and JobB individually via [Rundeck API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#running-a-job) from JobC using the [inline-script step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step).

Due to the big gap between 2.11.4 and 3.4.6 I recommend you to create a fresh 3.4.6 instance and import all projects, keys, and nodes. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery).

Comment: I did updated to 3.4.8.  but still same issue . like my Job A use one property from project A node.appserver:domain-user which is not define in project C. So its falling saying "sudo: unknown user: ${node.appserver:domain-user}". But if I ran the JOB A directly from Project A its working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding key of nodes used in JOB A & JOB B to project C may solve this issue.
First save the keys using "Key Storage Option" then under project settings > Default Node Executors > SSH Key Storage Path Browse to those keys and save.

It may be because of Nodes of job A & B are not accesible by project C.